# Powershell Get-History to String

Tags: string, powershell, type-conversion

how do I convert the following object to a string?

```
Get-History -Count 1 | Select-Object -Property 'CommandLine'
```

Comment: `Select-Object -Property 'CommandLine'` -> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'CommandLine'`

Comment: (Get-History -Count 1).CommandLine